# iOS. Apply another scroll animation when UIScrollView is scrolling

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview, scroll

I have UIScrollView with verticall scroll and a button which doesn't belong this scrollview and calls animated moving of this scrollview aside (not scrolling).

If I touch up this button and the scrollview is scrolling at the same time then app waits when the scrollview's animation is finished and then calls the animation from the button.

How to make these animations working simultaneously?

Or maybe are there any ways to stop all the scrollview animations except of checking all the subviews (because there are could be a lot of various scrollviews)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by calling an animation directly without performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
But sometimes this wouldn't work